# Utilizing <template> or DocumentFragment in an appropriate manner

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

I wrote this code, it actually works, and I'm going to use this strategy in an active project that's due in January.

I don't know web components yet -- the best I can personally utilize is [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) and [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).  But, I don't think I need the latter.

My goal was to use modules with HTML templates that I can pull in, change values (like form inputs, element attributes, etc).

I'm not using `DocumentFragment` at all, since I already *return* a document fragment with `return template.content`.

Am I still in compliance with this statement, considering the strategy I'm using?

> Changes made to the fragment don't affect the document (even on reflow) or incur any performance impact when changes are made.

Is there a more acceptable way to ingest templates, modify them, then append it to the DOM?

templates.js

```
function basicModal() {
    
    const template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `
    <div id="someModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;

    return template.content;

}


export { basicModal };
```

Modal/Form Handler

```
import { basicModal } from './templates.js';

function renderRetireeForm() {

    //get the template
    const myTemplate = basicModal();
    
    //modify the contents of the modal here
    //add some Forms to this structure (not shown)
    //I can change the input values, too
    myTemplate.querySelector('.modal').setAttribute('id', 'zzzModal')

    //append the template to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(myTemplate);

    // get a reference to what I just appended to the DOM
    const myModal = document.getElementById('zzzModal');



    // bootstrap stuff for dealing with the Modal that I just appended
    myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        console.log('--the modal is open')
        // do more stuff to the modal if desired
    });

    myModal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
        console.log('--the modal is closed removed')
        $(this).remove();
    });

    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(myModal, {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        focus: true,
    })

    modal.show()



}
export { renderRetireeForm };
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are using `<template>` right.
It was created so that you can have templates in your HTML code without you having to hide those templates. In your case you could have used `<div>` and it would have had little or no impact.

Other than that,

- I think some of your comments are too obvious (`//get the template`)
- You are too generous with newlines
- The prefix of `my` in variable names seems odd, why `my`?
- This

  ```
    const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(myModal, {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        focus: true,
    })

    modal.show()
  ```

  could be

  ```
    (new bootstrap.Modal(myModal, {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        focus: true,
    })).show()
  ```

Comment: The commenting & variables were more for demonstration to the code reviewers.  I agree with your comment about `<template>`, so I'm going to move them into html.  Also, I like your self-opening modal example.  Thank you!